# Merge two MySQL queries and replace result

Tags: mysql

I want to find a way to use one query where I am replacing the LineUps.DIG output when it = Y. I'm wanting to mark as an asterisk in html. maybe it's better to do this on the front end vs sql query.

Fist query works and returns the data

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT distinct Channel_LineUps.channel, Channel_LineUps.description, Channel_LineUps.Tier, LineUps.HD, LineUps.DIG FROM Channel_LineUps, LineUps WHERE (LineUps.Market_ID = Channel_LineUps.Market_ID AND Channel_LineUps.Market_ID = 28) ORDER BY Channel_LineUps.Tier ASC");
```

Second query is where i have the replace but am not sure how to merge with above query.

```
SELECT DIG,REPLACE(DIG,"Y","*") as output FROM LineUps WHERE DIG="Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [CASE WHEN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/) is what you are looking for:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT Channel_LineUps.channel, Channel_LineUps.description,
Channel_LineUps.Tier, LineUps.HD,
CASE LineUps.DIG WHEN "Y" THEN REPLACE(LineUps.DIG, "Y", "*") ELSE LineUps.DIG END
FROM Channel_LineUps, LineUps
WHERE (LineUps.Market_ID = Channel_LineUps.Market_ID
AND Channel_LineUps.Market_ID = 28)
ORDER BY Channel_LineUps.Tier ASC
SQL;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

You can also directly replace line 4 above with:

```
CASE LineUps.DIG WHEN "Y" THEN "*" ELSE LineUps.DIG END
```

as you know its value for sure.

Comment: Hmmm, seems not to work at the moment. I'll see if maybe this needs modified slightly since and making the query from within a php script. I failed to mention that there are two values for DIG. Y or N. I wonder if I need to account for N somehow. I do not want to print N at all. Only want to take any result that is Y and replace with *

Comment: You can add LineUps.DIG = "Y" in the where clause.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. I'm wondering if I should use php code to do the replace. I'll need to do some research.